# How to arrange multiple NSViews side-by-side?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am building an application, where I need to put two seperate `NSViews` side-by-side when in fullscreen mode. As I have seen, probably there are two ways to do this, either I can make a super `NSView` and two subviews, or put two `NSViews` in a `NSWindow`. The problem is that though the process works for me for one `NSView`, I can't put them together at the same time. The method `setContentView:` allows me to set only one view for a window. And the method `setSubViews:` covers up the whole of the `NSView`. How can one specify the exact coordinated of the views to place and size them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An NSWindow only has one root NSView... and that's the Window's `contentView`.  Store any other views in that root view.

Using the Interface Builder offers an easy way of configuring the location/size of views in a graphical way.. but you can manually configure their **frames** with something around the lines of :

```
NSView *myView = [[MyCustomView alloc] init];
[[myWindow contentView] addSubview:myView];
[myView setFrame:NSMakeRect( /* ... */ )];
```

Some reading : [NSView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsview_Class/Reference/NSView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set one NSView as contentView of NSWindow and add the other two NSView's on using -`addSubview` method of NSView